# Replace character of a string with the character from an array

Tags: javascript, replace, character

I'm trying to make a script that changes text into these cool looking letters, it looks like everything should be working but when I try to send the replaced message it gives me a character like a white question mark on a  black background. This: �

Here's the code:

```
  var mm = "test";
  var alphabet = "";
  var nalphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";    
  for(var z in mm){
    var x = nalphabet.indexOf(mm[z].toLowerCase());
    var ool = alphabet[x];
    msg.channel.sendMessage(ool);
  }
```

Comment: Those whiet chars with the question mark in it are a sign of bad encoding. This means there is at least two types of encoding involded, usually ASCII and UTF8. Check your database, files and HTTP headers encoding.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to change a string like `"test"` into `""`, is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is all about the coding of characters. Each of your cool-looking letters has length 2. So when you try to get such character directly by index, you receive just a half of it. As a solution you can try to join two sibling characters. Something like this

```
  var mm = "test";
  var alphabet = "";
  var nalphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";    
  for(var z in mm){
    var x = nalphabet.indexOf(mm[z].toLowerCase());
    var ool = alphabet[x * 2] + alphabet[x * 2 + 1];
    msg.channel.sendMessage(ool);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var message = "test";
var alphabet = ["","","","","",
                "","","","","",
                "","","","","",
                "","","","","",
                "","","","","",""];
var nalphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";    
for(var letter in message) {
    var x = nalphabet.indexOf(message[letter].toLowerCase());
    var ool = alphabet[x];
    document.write(ool);
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfs08nfL/).